# Why PostgreSQL merge join is only used in equijoin while Oracle supports non-equijoin?

Tags: postgresql

I've read some article that mentioned MERGE JOIN is only used in equijoin in Postgres. But I know in Oracle  MERGE JOIN [can work in non-equijoin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/joins.html#GUID-3F935776-FE28-4350-9FA4-E6B47489156E):

> The optimizer may choose a sort merge join over a hash join for joining large amounts of data when any of the following conditions is true: The join condition between two tables is not an equijoin, that is, uses an inequality condition such as <, <=, >, or >=.

I am wondering why Postgresql MERGE JOIN cannot be used in non-equijoin.

Comment: "ORACLE MERGE JOIN can work in non-equijoin" -- can you support this claim with some source?

Comment: @mustaccio the Oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/joins.html#GUID-3F935776-FE28-4350-9FA4-E6B47489156E “ The optimizer may choose a sort merge join over a hash join for joining large amounts of data when any of the following conditions is true:

The join condition between two tables is not an equijoin, that is, uses an inequality condition such as <, <=, >, or >=.”

Comment: The answer to "why doesn't program x have feature y" can nearly always be answered with "because nobody had the resources to do it" or alternatively: "because nobody cared enough to implement it"

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for editing my question that makes the question clear.I'm poor in English